# How to temporary turn NFS server read-only?

Tags: linux, nfs

I want to build a family NAS at home. I want to use SnapRAID for integrity. So, it needs to run SnapRaid sync periodically. The sync process requires the data is not being changed while it is running, however. So, I need to make a script that does this:

1. Check that no files are being written over the NFS shares at the moment.
2. If they are, wait and repeat
3. Make NFS read-only
4. Run sync
5. Make NFS RW again

The questions are:

1. How to do #1?
2. How to do #3 without causing too much alarm on the client side? I can `mount -remount,ro` the drives themselves, or edit `/etc/shares`. Or is there another way?

Advise me please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lsof +d /yournfsshare` will tell you if there are any open files on the share at the moment you're running the script. This may change 2 seconds later. I would recommend using the `mount -o remount,ro /yournfsshare` to set the share read-only and remount again `rw` when you're done.